# progressbar doesn't show on screen

Tags: android, android-activity, progress-bar

I need to show a second activity after the progress bar is filled. I tried the code below but it doesn't show the progress bar and just shows my second activity.

This is the code:

```java
   public class MiSuper2 extends Activity {
        String strListas[] = null;
        private ProgressBar mProgress;
        private int mProgressStatus = 0;
        private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        private StoreData stdArticulos = null;
        public Cursor cursor = null;
        private long fileSize = 0;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        stdArticulos = new StoreData(this);

        fileSize = 0;
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        stdArticulos = new StoreData(this);
        cursor = stdArticulos.leerArticulos();

        mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar_activity);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (mProgressStatus < 100) {
                    mProgressStatus = doWork();

                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            mProgress.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }).start();

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do{
                strListas[cursor.getPosition()] = cursor.getString(cursor.getPosition());
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }       

        Intent intent = new Intent(MiSuper2.this, PntArticulo.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    public int doWork() {       
        while (fileSize <= 1000000) {
            fileSize++;
            return (int) fileSize;
        }
        return 100;
    }
}
```

This is the main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imvLogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/presentacion" 
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar_activity"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="100dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please help

Comment: do you need any particular  time for moving or just like a splash screen

Comment: What is shown on the first screen? When you examine main.xml in the eclipse view editor, does it show the bar? Also, don't hesitate to use Log.d(String,String) statements to see what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using the `doWork()` function to take up time so that you're progress bar does something. Even though you wrote a big loop, it still executes very quickly so you don't see your progress bar move. Rather, you want to simulate your Thread doing something computationally intensive by using `Thread.sleep()` which takes an argument that is the time to sleep in milliseconds.

Try changing your code to this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        while (mProgressStatus < 100) {
            try {
                mProgressStatus += doWork();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mProgress.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                }
            });
        }

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
                public void run() {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MiSuper2.this, Second.class));
                }
            });
        }
}).start();
```

And...

```
public int doWork() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    return 1;
}
```

This will increment your progress bar by 1% every second. And finally, the documentation on `Thread.sleep()`: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)

EDIT: Ramz beat me to this answer, but doesn't provide an explanation of why it's the answer. Hopefully my explanation helps.

EDIT2: I think you edited your questions since I started looking at it a second time. You had some errors in your XML before, but now it is gone. Regardless, your problem is now that you need the call to `startActivity()` inside your worker thread. Otherwise, the UI thread does not wait for the `doWork()` function to return and immediately starts the other Activity when your app starts. Sorry, I should have mentioned this before. The code I posted above is updated with this change.

Comment: Thank for the answer shanet i use your example code but still just show the second activity but progress bar don't

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code  **SplashScreen.java**

```
package com.cud.point;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

 ProgressBar bar;

 TextView txt;

 int total=0;

 boolean isRunning=false;

 // handler for the background updating

 Handler handler=new Handler() {

 @Override

 public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

 total=total+20;

 String perc=String.valueOf(total).toString();

 txt.setText(perc+"% completed");

 bar.incrementProgressBy(20);

 }

 };

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.splash);

bar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progress);

 txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
 Handler x = new Handler();
 x.postDelayed(new SplashHandler(), 5000);
 }
 class SplashHandler implements Runnable 
 {

    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplication(),YourSecound Activity.class));
        SplashScreen.this.finish();
    }


}

public void onStart() {

 super.onStart();

 // reset the bar to the default value of 0

 bar.setProgress(0);

  // create a thread for updating the progress bar

 Thread background=new Thread(new Runnable() {

 public void run() {

 try {

 for (int i=0;i<5 && isRunning;i++) {

 // wait 100ms between each update

 Thread.sleep(1000);

 handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage());

 }

 }

 catch (Throwable t) {

   }     }     });

 isRunning=true;

  // start the background thread

 background.start();

 }

 public void onStop() {

 super.onStop();

 isRunning=false;

 }

}
```

**splash.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="15px" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Loading......" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/splash" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
    android:max="100" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is an example of my project so please make necessary change in xml file

Comment: Thaks Ramz for your help, that's exactly what i need, works fine

Comment: its ok you got the solution please Accept this answer